# Local Mollification of a $L^1$ function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $f$ be a $L^1(\Omega)$ function, where $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a smooth and bounded domain. Then can we find a fuction $\phi\in W_0^{2,2}$ suct that $\phi>0$ in $\Omega$ and $\int_\Omega f\phi >0$?

Comment: not if $f=0$ ...

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention if $f\neq 0$.

Comment: I am inclined to say no, considering an oscillating $f$ like $\sin (1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ on the unit disk.

Comment: your example seems to be contradicting the statement but I found this in a paper and they are saying that we can consider $\phi$ to be the local mollification of $f$.